# breezejs fetching metadata when creating a new Entity

Tags: angularjs, metadata, breeze

When I call the following code:

```
function createMandat (initialValues) {
        return manager.createEntity('Mandate');
}
```

It fails because the type 'Mandate' is unknown. That I understand because I haven't yet fetched any entities of that type when I call this function.

So my question is, in case the metadataStore has no knowledge of a type, how can I force a round-trip to the server in order to get metadata for this type ? What is the best place in my code for doing so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call *manager.fetchMetadata* and then perform your *createEntity* call after promise resolution.

```
 manager.fetchMetadata().then(function() {
    var newMandate = manager.createEntity("Mandate");
    ...
 });
```

You do not need to do this if you perform a query first, because query execution implicitly does a fetchMetadata if it can't find the metadata before executing the query.  So the following will work as well.

```
manager.executeQuery(myQuery).then(function(data) {
    results = data.results;
    var newMandate = manager.createEntity("Mandate");
    ...
 });
```

Comment: I had not noticed the fetchMetadata() function...  Thanks ! Actually is there a way to detect that the call to fetchMetadata is required ? In other words, can I detect that metadata hasn't been loaded yet ?

Comment: Yes. See [MetadataStore.hasMetadataFor](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_hasMetadataFor)