# Fetching details on an entity in Breeze using Employee('1234')

Tags: breeze

I want fetch the details of a Collection in Odata services like the following URL
http://my.company.com/odata/Employee('1234')/Details

I tried with the following code to do so. Not sure whether fromEntityKey is the right thing to do or anything else.

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(collectionData.serviceName);
var empType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Employees");
var entityKey = new EntityKey(empType, '1234');
var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey);
```

But it gives me an error "Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first."

I also tried that from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143900/breezejs-fetching-metadata-when-creating-a-new-entity). But I'm still getting the same.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Where are you defining your metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *manager.metadataSote.getEntityType("Employees")* until metadata has been retrieved from the server.  By default this occurs during the first query operation, but your code is attempting to use the metadata before it has been retrieved.

Also, I think that you are confusing the name of your resource "Employees" with the type of the instances returned by your resource, probably "Employee".  I would also check whether your key's datatype is numeric or a string.  The example below assume its numeric (unlike your example where the datatype of the key is presumably a string because you are quoting it).

So you have two approaches, either force the metadata to be fetched before you compose your query, like this:

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () { 
    var empType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Employee");
    var entityKey = new EntityKey(empType, 1);
    var query = EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey);
    // if you want to also see the queries details 
    query = query.expand("Details");
    return manager.executeQuery(query);
}).then(function (data) {
    var results = data.results;
    ok(results.length === 1, "should have returned a single record");
    var emp = results[0];
));
```

or if you know the string name of the 'key' ("Id" in the example below) field, use it directly

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
  .where("Id", "==", 1)
  .expand("Details");
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
  var results = data.results;
  var emp = results[0];
});
```

Comment: I'm getting another error when I fetch It
the error is [link](http://pastebin.com/BvYPBaY9)

BTW my webservices response is in XML format and it is fetched fine.